# How to share Google Service Account Calendar with users

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have setup a service account for a Google Calendar project and can create new calendars just fine.  I need to be able to share those new service account calendars with other users but cannot find any references fromm those who might have tried to do this.  After a new calendar is created by the service account, I want the users individual calendars to begin showing this new calendar in the Google Calendar GUI. All the references I've found seem to do the reverse - allow a service account to see and manage other users' calendars.  Any insight would be much appreciated.